# Django TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class when trying to create a simple tag

Tags: django, django-templates

When trying to create a simple tag in django to reassign a variable in a django template, I am getting the error TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class.

custom_templates.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def define(val=None):
    return val
```

part of my settings.py:

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "crispy_forms",
    "crispy_bootstrap4",
    "main.apps.MainConfig",
    "register.apps.RegisterConfig",
    "main.customtemplates.custom_templates.define"
]
...
```

I believe this is everything interacting with my simple tag, if any other information is required, please let me know.
Any help is appreciated!

I've tried giving the val argument in my define function a preset value, I've tried removing this, and I've tried giving type suggestions,
e.g.,
`def define(val:bool):`